# Style button created using DOM property?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here I am adding button dynamically inside the list tag. Buttons are appearing close to list and I am trying to move it right. Is there any way we can do that when button created by dom. Need guidance on this.

```
{
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Add To Favourite";
    button.setAttribute('onclick',
        'addFavourite("' + movie['title'] + '")');
    data.appendChild(button);
}
```

Comment: Does `button.style.float = "right";` help you?

Comment: Here you go https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `float: right;` to move your button to rightmost side of `<li>`. You can also use `margin-left: 40px;` to move it few spaces to right of `<li>`

```js
var data = document.getElementById('container');
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Add To Favourite";  
button.className = 'liBtn';
button.setAttribute('onclick',
'addFavourite("sss")');
data.appendChild(button);
```

```css
.liBtn{
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id='container'>List 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: its moving too far right, how can we make few spaces or adjust width?

Comment: @Shiva use `margin-left: 40px;` then. Check the updated answer

Comment: its not showing effect but i have added the correct path of css file @ankit

Answer (score 0):

if u want to adjust try `margin-left`. Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cs0mrukb/5/)  I have written for your case. Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly inline property `float or margin` (button.style.float = "right")

Or you can set inline style using `el.style` and pass all of your styles in this string. Something like this:

```
// Create element
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Add To Favourite";                     
button.setAttribute('onclick', addFavourite("'+movie['title']+'"));

// Styling
var styleButton = "float: right; margin-left: 10px;";
button.setAttribute('style', styleButton);

// append
data.appendChild(button);
```

Using float: [Float CSS property MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

Using Margin: [Margin CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

Comment: elt is not defined or used anywhere here?

Comment: Sorry @Shiva it was `button` instead of `elt`. =D